# Coaching youth division D basketball

Tags: basketball, coaching

I've committed to coaching in a young kids (age 5-6) basketball league. This is pretty beginner so there's no keeping track of score, the main idea is for the kids to have fun and learn at the same time. What are some good practice techniques that will keep the kids motivated and teach them good basketball skills at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question, and i have a few links that i think will help.
this first one is a link to a few tips on how to keep basketball practice fun.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/tips-for-making-basketball-practice-fun.html

the second one is a few fun games related to basketball that you could play at your practices.

http://www.livestrong.com/article/373967-fun-kids-games-to-play-at-basketball/

well, i hope this helps.

Comment: Great tips in the first link, thanks. I wish there is more information though, ie how do you implement "Keep the kids active; don’t force them to stand in lines." I definitely can see that being important and want to avoid it, but at the same time don't want kids going crazy all over the place as they will tend to do.

Comment: And some really good ideas in the second link as well! I can probably only work with the bean bag one for this age group since defense is not an emphasis.

Comment: Links, by themselves, [do not fundamentally answer the question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). What excerpts from either reference can you use to answer the OPs question?